# Using Javascript inside Type Class Symfony

Tags: javascript, php, symfony, twig, symfony4

I'd like to create a form to import some data. But this form require one information called `Constructeur`. On my website you can create some `Constructeur` . But for my page I want the user be able to Select a constructeur if Exist or if not check a box and then a Form will appear and the user is going to be able to create a new `Constructeur`.

The problem is that I don't how to do this with Symfony 4. I generate my forms by using the `make:form` command.

Here is my current Controller (the code to create a constructeur is not yet here)

**CatalogueController**

```php
class CatalogueController extends AbstractController
{
    /**
     * @Route("/admin/catalogues/create", name="admin.catalogues.new")
     * @param Request $request
     * @return RedirectResponse | Response
     */
    public function new(Request $request)
    {
        $catalogue = new Catalogue();
        $form = $this->createForm(CatalogueType::class, $catalogue);
        $form->handleRequest($request);

        if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()){
            $this->em->persist($catalogue);
            $this->em->flush();
            $this ->addFlash('success', 'Catalogue crée avec succès');
            return $this->redirectToRoute('admin.catalogues.index');
        }
        return $this->render('/admin/catalogues/create.html.twig', [
            'catalogue' => $catalogue,
            'form' => $form->createView()
        ]);
    }
//some codes
}
```

Here is my 
CatalogueType(you can see the `constructeur_id`

**CatalogueType**

```php
class CatalogueType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('catalogue_date_debut', DateType::class, [
                'widget' => 'single_text',
                'html5' => false,
                'attr' => ['class' => 'datepicker'],
            ])
            ->add('catalogue_date_fin', DateType::class, [
                'placeholder' => 'Sélectionner un date de début',
                'widget' => 'single_text',
                'html5' => false,
                'attr' => ['class' => 'datepicker'],
            ])
            ->add('is_active', CheckboxType::class, [
                'label'    => 'Le catalogue est-il actif ?',
                'value' => 0,
                'required' => false,
            ])
            ->add('entreprise_id')
            ->add('contructeur_id')
        ;
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'data_class' => Catalogue::class,
        ]);
    }
}
```

And here is my view and how I implement my form

**create.html.twig**

```html
{% extends 'admin/baseadmin_html.twig' %}

{% block title %}Créer un Catalogue{% endblock %}


{% block body %}
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col s12 m12 l12">
            <div class="card white">
                <div class="card-content black-text">
                    <span class="card-title">Créer un Catalogue</span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col s12 m12 l12">
            <div class="card-panel ">
                <div class="row">

                    {{ form_start(form) }}
                    {{ form_widget(form) }}


                    <button class="btn s12 m6 l3">{{ button|default('Enregister') }}</button>
                    {{ form_end(form) }}
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

So here is My question. How could I allow my user when they Check a box to Hide the select on my `constructeur_id`and show a new input where user is going to write the constructeur name (i know how to do this later with the controller but how can i deal with the view.)

Answer (score 0):

You can embed a form into another in Symfony : https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/embedded.html

So by default the select AND the embeded form will be addded to your form in the view.

Then you just need a little bit of JS to mask the embeded form hidden by default and toggle the two elements as needed depending if the checkbox is checked or not and voilà!

btw, if Contructeur and Enterprise are entities, you can use the EntityType to display a select (Doctrine will handle the association when saving).